# issue with HTML navbar border

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, border, navbar, nav

The navbar has a bottom border that I've been playing around with for hours and I can't figure out how to get rid of it: 
[image]

I'm slightly confused about which class this falls under:

```css
.navbar{
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-header, .navbar-right > li > a{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Robato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-brand row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img id="logo" src="images/badge.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-5 text-left text-uppercase" id="headtext">
      Chicago Chapter of Delta Upsilon Fraternity
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="leadership.html">Leadership</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: provide a working example please.

Comment: i don't see the bottom border, am i missing something? could you not just use border-style:none to get rid of the border

Answer (score 0):

i am able to see the border bottom to the anchor tags. for that you can use.this is what is understand from your fiddle.

```
ul li a
{ 
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Neither this nor boder-style: none; worked. When I tried doing what you suggested but instead did decoration: dotted, it highlighted a box within the line but not the line itself. I guess my question coul be answered with which element is producing this?